# What's wrong with this argument? (Diagonalizable matrices and spectral theorem)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Please consider all matrices to be in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Let $A$ be a positive definite symmetric matrix and $B$ a symmetric matrix. Then $A$ represent a positive definite scalar product $\Phi$ in an Euclidean space $V$. On the other hand $B$ represents some self adjoint operator in $End(V)$. For the Spectral theorem there exists some matrix $P\in O_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $P^tAP=Id$ and $P^tBP=P^{-1}BP=D$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix.

There must be something wrong with this argument, otherwise $A$ and $B$ would be simultaneously diagonalisable and therefore $AB=BA$.

thank you

Comment: Why do you think that the matrix $P$ is the same for both of them? If $P$ is orthogonal, then $P^TAP$ is diagonal and not $Id$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, this is indeed the case.

I think you just forgot one detail: if you want to apply the spectral theorem, $B$ must be self adjoint *with respect to* the scalar product defined by matrix $A$.

This means that you have

$$
(BX)^t AY = X^tA(BY) \qquad \Longleftrightarrow \qquad X^t(BA)Y = X^t(AB)Y
$$

for all $X,Y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Which implies $AB = BA$.

That is, once you say that $B$ is self adjoint with respect to $A$, you're assuming that both matrices commute.

And then the spectral theorem tells you, indeed, that there exists an orthonormal basis (with respect to the scalar product defined by matrix $A$) of eigenvectors of the self adjoint operator defined by matrix $B$. In other words, there is an orthogonal matrix $P$ such that

$$
P^t A P = I \qquad \text{and} \qquad P^tBP = D \ ,
$$

where $D$ is a diagonal matrix.